# php сокеты, ошибка использования socket_connect

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, веб-сервер

Есть нейронная сеть, ожидающая запросов от сервера, написанного на php. При клике я со страницы отправляю запрос на сервер и получаю ответ. Так как программа маленькая, я не хотел использовать вебсокет и решил использовать ajax: я делаю запрос на страницу php и оттуда делаю запрос на сервер, т.к. php socket проще. При первом запросе все все идет хорошо. Но при втором запросе, когда 1 уже закончен, появляется ошибка на (1):

```
Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)
```

Я не знаю, в чем дело, ведь 1 запрос уже закончен, и адрес уже должен быть свободным. Помогите понять мне мою ошибку. Вот код:

JS

```js
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://nnet.am/query.php',
            ...
```

query.php

```php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 80);
socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 2083); // (1)
socket_write($socket, $data);
$data = socket_read($socket, 1024);
socket_close($socket);

echo $data;
```

SERVER

```php
...
$socket = stream_socket_server('127.0.0.1:2083', $errno, $errstr);

if(!$socket) die("Socket fault!");
print "Server is ready!\n";
while($connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, -1)) {
    print "New connection!\n";
    $data = json_decode(fread($connect, 1024));
    input($data, $n);
    print "Entered!\n";
    calc($n, $w);
    print "Counted!\n";
    fwrite($connect, json_encode(result($n)));
    fclose($connect);
}
```

Comment: Где именно он появляется? На какой линии кода и файла?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov возле написан (1) в файле query.php

Comment: Видимо ваш PHP код неправильно заканчивает исполнение в виде необработанной ошибки или исключения, вследствие чего сокет не закрывается до конца. Используйте error_reporting(E_ALL) в PHP файлах, так же перед второй отправкой проверьте через netstat если сокет был закрыт: если нет, то нужно выяснять почему файл не заканчивает работу корректно.